# How to work with recommended baselines using Jenkins ClearCase plugin?

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, baseline

I'm using Jenkins 1.596 with ClearCase Plug-in 1.5.3.

SCM is UCM ClearCase.

My job is currently polling against the stream and if new work has been delivered, it will create a new view.

1. Developers manually recommend baselines. Is it possible to poll for the event of baseline recommendation?
2. When view is created by the plugin, is it possible to instruct it to use the recommended baseline? Currently, it's picking up latest version even though no new baselines have been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1/ Is it possible to poll for the event of baseline recommendation?

Not that I know of.

> 2/ is it possible to instruct it to use the recommended baseline?

No: an UCM view is by definition selecting the LATEST versions on the branch associated to that stream.

Another approach would be to have a *sub*-stream, which you could then rebase: by default, the rebase should pick the recommended baseline of the parent stream.
The job could then used that rebased view.

But that means a non-standard job UCM setting, with a non-standard polling policy, like a first job checking if there is any new baseline (job launched every few minutes), and if there is one, calling a second job (for the rebase)

Answer (score 0):

There's two approaches you could use, off the top of my head:

1) Create a BUILDME stream off Integration, based on the recommended baseline. Then ask your administrators to implement a trigger which updates your BUILDME stream each time a new baseline is recommended (that's a cleartool chstream command, if memory serves).

2) Use a script which runs as a scheduled job, which looks up the recommended baseline (cleartool desc -l stream:, then look for "  recommended baselines"), then looks at the timestamp for that baseline (cleartool lsbl ).

I've used the latter before, with a client who had >200 Projects.

Comment: Thanks, Garry. Please leave your answer for others who have similar challenges. I only accepted VonC, as it slightly more closely matches my questions. But I took your notes as well for a future use case. Very valuable information.